# How get the law of Total Probability?

Tags: probability

In general, Simpson's Paradox can be shown as follows. $A,A^c,B,B^c, C \ $ and $\  C^c$ are some arbitrary events:

$$
P( A | B , C) < P(A| B^c,C)\\
P(A|B,C^c)<P(A|B^c,C^c)\\
But,\\
P(A|B)>P(A|B^c)
$$
Can someone show me a step-by-step way to arrive to the Law of Total Probability as following?
$$
P(A|B)=P(A|B,C)P(C|B)+P(A|B,C^c)P(C^c|B)
$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only need to know the definition of the conditional probability and the law of total probability. We have that
\begin{align*}
P(A\mid B)&=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}\\
&=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C^c)}{P(B)}\\
&=\frac{P(A\mid B\cap C)P(B\cap C)+P(A\mid B\cap C^c)P(B\cap C^C)}{P(B)}\\
&=P(A\mid B\cap C)P(C\mid B)+P(A\mid B\cap C^c)P(C^C\mid B).
\end{align*}

Comment: @macroe You're welcome!